# Create only ONE table with Flask + SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web application based on MySQL DBMS
I followed the tutorial in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22422817/2024665) in which it creates all the tables related to every model calling the **create_all()**.

The only one thing I don't understand is how to **create only one table** and not all of them. I searched through google but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use [create](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.create) method

```
Model.__table__.create(session.bind)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! 
I only want to notice one thing for coherence with the example I linked: the correct way to do this is **Model.__table__.create(db.session.bind, checkfirst=True)**

Comment: This also works with drop: Model.__table__.drop(db.session.bind)